# Reading a text file in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, textinput, text-parsing

I have looked at several other peoples problems similar to this on the site but have found nothing to help solve this... So I am trying to read in a text file, which is the same directory as my main program and I have also imported it into the project itself the code is below followed by its output, any suggestions are welcome, thank you!

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"allshows" 
                                    ofType:@"txt"];
NSLog(@"filePath: %@", filePath);

NSString *fileString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
NSLog(@"fileString: %@", fileString);

NSArray *lines = [fileString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];  
NSLog(@"arrayLines: %@", lines);
```

and the output looks like this:

```
filePath: (null)
fileString: (null)
arrayLines: (null)
```

as I mentioned, the file "allshows.txt" is in the same directory as "Epguides.m" (main directory).

Any idea what I am missing? This is my first real attempt at a program in Objective C if that wasn't evident lol

Thanks!

SOLVED - THANK YOU FOR YOUR EFFORTS.

Comment: Is the file included in the project? Otherwise it will not be bundled with the app in the compile process and not be accessible at runtime

Comment: I think so, I added the file into the actual project window as in, I did - Project > add to project > selected the file and it popped up in the list of files in the project along with the rest.

Comment: You can check it in the project settings to make sure that it is included in the copy resources stage of the build. This is in your target then Build Phases and then copy Bundle Resources

Answer (score 2):

Try this alternate method for getting the path and contents, this is a method i am currently using in a project:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]; 
NSString *xmlPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"periodic.xml"]; 
NSString *xmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:xmlPath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

it is loading an xml, but it is just plain text anyway, should work for you

Comment: I made the changes you suggested but still no luck =/ the output looks like this:

path: /Users/Didier/Documents/Programming/EpGuides/theList/EpGuides/build/Debug

xmlPath: /Users/Didier/Documents/Programming/EpGuides/theList/EpGuides/build/Debug/allshows.txt

xmlString: (null)

I even put a copy into that debug folder to see if that would help, nothing seems to have changed :(

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have included that file in your target.  Just having it in the program is not enough.  Specifically, in that target's build steps, make sure it gets copied to the output directory, which may not be where you're thinking you're executing from. (Common mistake by people is to look where their project is or in the 'release' bin folder instead of the debug, or vice-versa. (...and if you do add it to the step, make sure you're aware that it gets overwritten every time you compile and build.)

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting `null` back from the `pathForResource` call is because there is no file in the bundle matching that name.

Just because it's in the file system next to your source files, doesn't mean it will be copied to the .app bundle.

Check the "Copy Bundle Resources" step in your target's build settings, and make sure the file is listed in there.

Comment: I don't think it was to begin with so I added a new copy bundle resources phase and added the file to it but the same problem is happening, this is was my file tree looks like if that helps:

http://didierd.co.uk/CBR.png

Comment: What does `[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]` give you?  What is inside of this directory?

Comment: thanks dude! managed to get this working! Just need to figure out how to print one element out of the array (ie - lines[0], lines[1] etc.. in java, any idea while I have your attention since that isnt the case in objective C?) Thank you for all your help mate!

Comment: To access array elements by index in obj-c use the method "objectAtIndex:index" So your code would be [lines objectAtIndex:0],[lines objectAtIndex:1], etc etc.

Comment: Just figured it out also, thank you all! have been a massive help! thanks again! :D

Answer (score 0):

> as I mentioned, the file "allshows.txt" is in the same directory as
>   "Epguides.m" (main directory).

When you say "main directory", do you mean your app bundle or the directory it is being compiled in?

That .m leads me to believe the latter, in which case you're using NSBundle incorrectly. NSBundle will locate files located in your app bundle, not files in your compilation directory.

In order to add something to your app bundle follow these steps.
1. Drag the item into your Xcode Project (in this case allshows.txt) inside of the group directory "Supporting Files" (you don't need to add it there,  but you might as well since its there).
2. Select your project on the left and go to the Build Phases tab.
3. If your file is not already in "Copy Bundle Resources", simply add it by dragging and dropping.

After doing this, you should be able accomplish what you're trying to do.

PS. If I was wrong in my assumption about the compile dir vs the app bundle.
Try passing @"" to ofType:, the type is just a hint to NSBundle for faster lookups.